# How do I join 2 dbSets in a repository relationship request using Linq / Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have the following code:

```
    public ActionResult ListByJames(int jamesID, int page = 1, string sort = "Name", bool desc = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<Bob> orderedBobs = bobRepository.SortByColumnName(sort, desc);
        IEnumerable<Bob_JamesRelationship> bobRelations = bobRelationshipRepository.Relationships;
        James james = jamesRepository.GetByID(jamesID);

        // At the moment, the following returning model just returns a 
        // list of Bobs, but I need to return a list of bobs that are 
        // related to the James that is passed through

        ListViewModel<Bob> model = new ListViewModel<Bob>
        {
            Items = orderedBobs
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = orderedBobs.Count(),
                Sort = sort,
                Desc = desc
            }
        };
        return View("_List", model);
    }
```

I need to make a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    James j
JOIN
    Bob_JamesRelationships r ON
    j.Id = r.JamesID
JOIN
    Bobs b ON
    b.Id = r.BobID
```

but in the style of my C# code using Linq

Note that the following lines

```
        IEnumerable<Bob> orderedBobs = bobRepository.SortByColumnName(sort, desc);
        IEnumerable<Bob_JamesRelationship> bobRelations = bobRelationshipRepository.Relationships;
        James james = jamesRepository.GetByID(jamesID);
```

contain all of the information required to get the required set of Bobs back.

A James is related to a Bob via a Bob_JamesRelationship... I also have 3 SQL tables that represent these too.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All collections must be `IQueryable` if you want them to be combined into one query. `IEnumerable` is always an in-memory object that has no connection to a query provider. `IQueryable` has an expression tree that its query provider can translate into the query language of the underlying data store. Expression trees from different `IQueryable` instances with the same provider can be combined into one by compose methods like `Join`.

So the first thing to do is return `IQueryable<T>` from your repositories. Second, make sure they share the same context instance. Then you can do things like

```
from bo in orderedBobs
join br in bobRelations on bo.Id equals br.BobId
join j in James on br.JamesId equals j.Id
where j.Id == jamesId
select new { bo, br, j }
```

and see it translated into one SQL statement. I can't judge whether this is a small step or a giant leap for your current architecture, but it's the way to go anyhow.

Comment: Do you have to return into a var type?... It comes back as an anonymous type

Comment: Ah I see, you can convert with .ToList and then cast it. no problem cool!